# Could not load type "Doctrine\DBAL\Types\StringType symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am new to Symfony and am stuck with this error:

> "Could not load type "Doctrine\DBAL\Types\StringType""

I haven't used any custom types and cannot find where  the error comes from. I was trying to do a create action using a Symfony sample. I did like they said but this error appears when I want to try the result.

Comment: Please post the code where you get this error

Comment: this should do the job \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType::class

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  I got confused and should have used the Symfony\Component  instead of the Doctrine\DBAL.

Thanks for the help.